# Cropping a rotated image in opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv

Ok so I am having problems cropping my rotated image in opencv. First off does it matter what order the points are in the array fed into minAreaRect? If not then I don't know what is wrong with my code but as soon as I crop the rotated image the cropped image is just a black square. I assume because my box is wrong somehow. Anyway here is my code. Edit: my method was fine the problem is my points for the roi are wrong.

```
                int len = max(ImageAd.cols, ImageAd.rows);
            cv::Point2f pt(len/2., len/2.);
            cv:: Mat r = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(pt, -angled, 1.0);
            cv::warpAffine(ImageAd, ImageAd, r, ImageAd.size(), INTER_CUBIC);
            vector<cv::Point> points;
            points.push_back(Pt3);
            points.push_back(Pt4);
            points.push_back(Pt1);
            points.push_back(Pt2);

            cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));
            cv::Size box_size = box.size;

            cv::getRectSubPix(ImageAd, box_size, box.center, ImageAd);
            cv::imshow("cropped", ImageAd);
```

Comment: why just not take a roi?

Comment: what are the coordinates of the rectangle? Can you run Point2f pts[4]; rect.points(pts); and print pts to make sure they are within your Mat bounds (they can be negative if your original point cloud is too close to the border).

Comment: nkint - roi is not a rotated rect. Its sides are aligned with the coordinates axes which is not always what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I never used getRectSubPix so I don't know exactly what is wrong but.. why do just not take a roi? the C++ API with `cv::Mat` class are very handy for this..

Here is a [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat), you can take a ROI (that is a Region of Interest if you don't know it yet) with the overloaded function call operator of `cv::Mat`

Anyway here is a snippet for take ROI

```
cv::Mat img = …;
cv::Mat subImg = img(cv::Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
cv::Mat subImg = img(cv::Range(0, 0), cv::Range(100, 100));
```

You have a `cv::RotatedRect` so you can directly use the `RotatedRect::boundingRect` property.

Comment: But I have a further question. The problem, I think, is actually that the points I have are wrong.I have used the four corners of the original non rotated image (0,0 :img.cols, 0 : img.cols, img.rows : 0, img.rows) as the points fed into minAreaRect which I'm guessing is wrong although I don't know what points I should use.

Comment: sorry but I think it's better to open a new question if this is totally another question..

Comment: (does this post answer your first question?)